# Evaluation of Bose-Einstein and Fermi-Dirac Integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Can anyone help me with the following integral, which has arisen from my study of cosmology?

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{p^2dp}{e^{(p\pm\mu)/T}+ 1}$$

I have tried substitution and using standard integral tables in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, but the change of variables alters the lower limit on the integral, so I'm not sure if standard definite integrals can then be applied.

I have also tried integrating by parts, but this just leads me to further similar integrals that I cannot evaluate.

I would basically like to know if the integral can be evaluated exactly, or if it is necessary to use a series expansion for the denominator.

*Update*

I have found an exact relation involving the original integral:

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{e^{(p-\mu)/T}+1}-\frac{1}{e^{(p+\mu)/T}+1}\right)p^2\;dp=\frac{T^3}{3}\left[\pi^2\left(\frac{\mu}{T}\right)+\left(\frac{\mu}{T}\right)^3\right]$$

However, I am not sure how this was evaluated either, but maybe it can help?

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? If you want our help we need to know your thoughts on the problem, so we can help you in the right way with what seems hard to you.

Comment: Wolfram's opinion: [+](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+p^2%2F%28e^%28%28p-mu%29%2FT%29%2B1%29dp) and [-](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+p^2%2F%28e^%28%28p-mu%29%2FT%29-1%29dp). Those $Li$ functions make me wonder where this integral came from.

Comment: First thing I'd do is a change of variable $y=(p-\mu)/T$, because in the case of $e^y-1$ in the denominator you will probably end up with the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(\cdot)$. Not totally sure on that one, would have to perform the substitution to be sure, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition to see what I'm getting at.

Comment: This might help: 
[Bose-Einstein integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose-Einstein_integral#Integral_representations)
and [Fermi-Dirac integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral).

Comment: @MickG they are the expectation values for the square of the momentum for a massless, relativistic Bose/Fermi gas at temperature $T$ and chemical potential $\mu$

Comment: You need to make a Series expansion as I did. But I forgot a term, so if you wait for a while, I'll edit the answer, providing to give you the exact resolution, or at least the best input for it.

Answer (score 6):

This is a derivation of the integral result provided by the OP in the Update.  The integral is

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dp \, p^2 \left (\frac1{e^{(p-\mu)/T}+1} - \frac1{e^{(p+\mu)/T}+1} \right ) &= 2 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \int_0^{\infty} dp \;\frac{p^2 \, e^{p/T}}{e^{2 p/T}+ 2 \cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}}\; e^{p/T} + 1} \\ &=  2 T^3 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \int_1^{\infty} dx \; \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}}\; x+1}\\ &= T^3 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \int_0^{\infty} dx \; \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}}\; x+1} \end{align}$$

In the second line, I subbed $p=T \log{x}$.

The last integral may be evaluated via contour integration by considering the following contour integral:

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log^3{z}}{z^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; z+1} $$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour of outer radius $R$ and inner radius $\epsilon$ about the positive real axis, i.e., so that $\arg{z} \in [0,2 \pi]$.  The contour integral is, as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$,

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^3{x} - (\log{x}+i 2 \pi)^3}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1} $$

which is equal to

$$-i 6 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1} + 12 \pi^2 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1}\\+ i 8 \pi^3 \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1}$$

Note that the second integral vanishes.  You can show this by subbing $x = 1/y$ and seeing that the integral is equal to the negative of itself.

On the other hand, the contour integral is also equal to the sum of the residues at the poles $z_+=-e^{\mu/T}$ and $z_-=-e^{-\mu/T}$.  The negative signs will be treated as factors of $e^{i \pi}$ because of the branch of the log we are using as defined by the contour $C$.  Thus, by the residue theorem,

$$-i 6 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1} + i 8 \pi^3 \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1} = i 2 \pi \left [\frac{\left (\frac{\mu}{T} + i \pi \right )^3}{-2 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}}} + \frac{\left (-\frac{\mu}{T} + i \pi \right )^3}{2 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}}} \right ]$$

We're almost done...except that we need the second integral on the left.  The good news is that we can evaluate it in precisely the same manner as we did the original integral, but with a factor of $\log{z}$ rather than $\log^3{z}$ in the numerator of the integrand.  Thus,

$$-i 2 \pi \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1} = i 2 \pi \left [\frac{\frac{\mu}{T} + i \pi }{-2 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}}} + \frac{-\frac{\mu}{T} + i \pi }{2 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}}} \right ]$$

or

$$\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1} = \frac{\mu}{T \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}}} $$

Thus, we have all the pieces in place to evaluate the integral.  We find that, upon expansion of the RHS and combining like terms, we get

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+2\cosh{\frac{\mu}{T}} \; x+1} = \frac1{3 \sinh{\frac{\mu}{T}}} \left [\left (\frac{\mu}{T} \right )^3 + \pi^2 \frac{\mu}{T} \right ]$$

Thus, our original integral is

> $$\int_0^{\infty} dp \, p^2 \left (\frac1{e^{(p-\mu)/T}+1} - \frac1{e^{(p+\mu)/T}+1} \right ) = \frac{T^3}{3} \left [\left (\frac{\mu}{T} \right )^3 + \pi^2 \frac{\mu}{T} \right ]$$

as asserted.

Comment: This is awesome!!

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much. Just one question: I see that the original integral can also be written as follows - does this simplify the procedure?

Comment: $\frac{p^2}{T^3}\sinh\frac{\mu}{T}\int_0^\infty\frac{p^2dp}{\cosh\frac{\mu}{T}+\cosh\frac{p}{T}}$

Comment: @dgwp: You're welcome.  I think, for the form you show, you can use a rectangle in the complex plane.  As far as complexity, I think you still have to use a higher power of $z$ in the numerator (as I used a higher power of $\log{z}$ in the numerator and evaluate at least one more integral.

Answer (score 4):

**Just for fun** (After all, integration is just art).

Suppose you set $(p - \mu)/T = z$ so d$z = \text{d}p/T$ and $p = zT + \mu$.

In this way you get:

$$\int_{-\mu/T}^{\infty} T\frac{(zT + \mu)^2}{e^z \pm 1}\ \text{d}z$$

you may collect $e^z$, getting

$$T\int_{-\mu/T}^{\infty}\frac{(zT + \mu)^2}{e^z (1 \pm e^{-z})}\ \text{d}z$$

Now usually when we deal with integral of this kind, we pull out a geometric series from the term

$$\frac{1}{1 \pm e^{-z}}$$

since $z$ is usually in the range $[0, +\infty)$. In this case the range is different, starting from a negative $\mu/T$ which could forbid us to generate the geometric series. We may have a try the same. The trick is the same either for $+$ and for $-$ so I'll give you the $-$ treatise.

$$\frac{1}{1 - e^{-z}} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (e^{-z})^k$$

thence

$$T\int_{-\mu/T}^{\infty} (zT + \mu)^2 e^{-z}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (e^{-zk})\ \text{d}z = T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\int_{-\mu/T}^{\infty} (zT + \mu)^2 e^{-z}(e^{-zk})\ \text{d}z$$

I think there is no close form for such an integration, but you can always try to split the square and see what happens..

$$T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\int_{-\mu/T}^{\infty} \left(z^2T^2 e^{-z(1+k)} + \mu^2 e^{-z(1+k)} + 2zT\mu e^{-z(1+k)}\right)\ \text{d}z$$

**Remark**

Due to the lower extrema of the integral, I'm not sure about the Geometric Series trick. I advice you to search for "Fermi-Dirac" integrals or "Bose-Einstein" integrals, since it appears exactly like one of them.

**Let's proceed**

Splitting the integrals into the three terms (leaving apart the series for the moment) we have the three integrals (valid for $\Re(k) > 0$) as follows:

$$\int_{-\mu/T}^{+\infty} z^2T^2e^{-z(1+k)}\ \text{d}z = T^2\frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)}\left(2 - \frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)\left(2 - \frac{\mu}{T}- \frac{\mu}{T}k\right)\right)}{(1+k)^3}$$

$$\int_{-\mu/T}^{+\infty} \mu^2 e^{-z(1+k)}\ \text{d}z = \mu^2 \frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)}}{1+k}$$

$$\int_{-\mu/T}^{+\infty} 2z\mu Te^{-z(1+k)}\ \text{d}z = 2T\mu\frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)} \left(1 - \frac{\mu}{T} -\frac{\mu}{T}k\right)}{(1+k)^2}$$

For each of these integrals, you have a series. With the help of the PoliLog special functions, you **could** evaluate those three series:

$$T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}T^2\frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)}\left(2 - \frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)\left(2 - \frac{\mu}{T}- \frac{\mu}{T}k\right)\right)}{(1+k)^3}$$

$$T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \mu^2 \frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)}}{1+k}$$

$$T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} 2T\mu\frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)} \left(1 - \frac{\mu}{T} -\frac{\mu}{T}k\right)}{(1+k)^2}$$

**Summation of Series - Mathematica will help**

I'm going now to write the summation of the three series saw below.

$$T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}T^2\frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)}\left(2 - \frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)\left(2 - \frac{\mu}{T}- \frac{\mu}{T}k\right)\right)}{(1+k)^3} = \frac{T^3}{8}\left(\frac{\mu^2}{T^2}e^{2\mu /T}\ _5F_4\left[\{ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2\}, \{1, 3, 3, 3\}e^{\mu /T}\right] - 16\text{PolyLog}[2, e^{\mu /T}] + 16\frac{\mu^2}{T^2}\text{PolyLog}[2, e^{\mu /T}] + 16\text{PolyLog}[3, e^{\mu /T}] - 8\frac{\mu^2}{T^2}\text{PolyLog}[3, e^{\mu /T}]\right)$$

$$T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \mu^2 \frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)}}{1+k} = T\mu^2\ \ln\left(1 - e^{\mu /T}\right)$$

$$T\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} 2T\mu\frac{e^{\frac{\mu}{T}(1+k)} \left(1 - \frac{\mu}{T} -\frac{\mu}{T}k\right)}{(1+k)^2} = 2T^2\mu\left(\frac{\mu}{T}\ln\left(1- e^{\mu}{T}\right) + \text{PolyLog}[2, e^{\mu /T}]\right)$$

**End of the Hell**

Thence the solution by series of your integral becomes:

$$
\frac{T^3}{8}\left(\frac{\mu^2}{T^2}e^{2\mu /T}\ _5F_4\left[\{ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2\}, \{1, 3, 3, 3\}e^{\mu /T}\right] - 16\text{PolyLog}[2, e^{\mu /T}] + 16\frac{\mu^2}{T^2}\text{PolyLog}[2, e^{\mu /T}] + 16\text{PolyLog}[3, e^{\mu /T}] - 8\frac{\mu^2}{T^2}\text{PolyLog}[3, e^{\mu /T}]\right) + T\mu^2\ \ln\left(1 - e^{\mu /T}\right) + 2T^2\mu\left(\frac{\mu}{T}\ln\left(1- e^{\mu}{T}\right) + \text{PolyLog}[2, e^{\mu /T}]\right)
$$

**More on special function involved**

Here for The generalized Hypergeometric Function $_qF_p$

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html

Here for the PolyLogarithm Function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html

Comment: perform the integral and use the series representation of the polylogarithms of order $1,2,3$ to finish it off

Comment: @tired I did it but.. infinite problems arose :P

Comment: might it be that u forgot the $e^z$ u pulled out the denomiator?

Comment: @tired GOSH! YOu're right! I will edit it ASAP! >.<

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL ^^

Comment: @tired Why did you voted it as off topic? It's about really interesting integral, even if well known in physics no one ever gave a resolution in textbooks as far as I know. Having fun here should be one of the aim of the site!

Comment: u are right, i somehow overlooked that the op did some serious efforts to answer the question (which was the original reason for close voting). Voted for reopening now. still waiting for a solution btw. :p

Comment: Kim, you are right - I've tried every cosmology textbook I could find. However, it sounds like statistical mechanics books should be the next place to look.

Comment: @dgwp Yes indeed! They are typical integrals in Statistical Mechanics, but I haven't find any treatment. Just the solution or some values.. So I wanted to write here a little explanation. Anyway,I forgot a term lol, so I will edit the question in the next hour!!

Comment: Please see update to original question...

Comment: @dgwp I wrote you the complete solution by series of the integral. Your edit has just been show by the other user!

Answer (score 0):

By the change of variable $\dfrac{p-\mu}T=t$, the integral is

$$T\int_{-\mu/T}^\infty \frac{(Tt+\mu)^2dt}{e^{t/T}\pm1}.$$

Because of the variable lower bound, you can consider it as an indefinite integral.

Then Wolfram gives no good news: the terms in $t^2$ and $t$ do imply expressions with $Li_2$ and $Li_3$, and no possible cancellation.